# .Net development on Ubuntu 22 and the development tool used

Tags: .net

Has anybody attempted MS .Net development on Mint 20 or Ubuntu 22.04? Does the MS stack work well on Linux or are there any caveats?
For development what is commonly used?MS visual studio,which isn't available under Linux or Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service pack 1 (Full Package)

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: for Linux development use .NET 5/6 not the Framework. As for the editor you can use VS code with some plugins to support C# lang

Comment: yes, you can develop in dotnet-core on 100% linux machines. note emphasis on dotnet-CORE (NOT "framework").  VS-Code is the "freebie", albeit a little cumbersome.  While there is a "community" edition for windows, I don't think there is for Mac.       JetBrains Rider is available (paid) for Mac (maybe regular linux)?  On Ubuntu, I was able to get Mono working with dotnet-core (a few years ago).

Comment: See, https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/    but as I see it, only VS-Code is downloadable for Linux (that are not mac specific).  https://www.mono-project.com/